# User interface error on background processing (blinking parts of screen)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, user-interface

I'm finishing an app which is integrated with an external device. This external device runs in a thread that can't be interrupted and I need to interact with the user through a view-animation, but sometimes the screen blinks and doesn't shows correctly.
While the device is processing, the screen doesn't shows any changes on the user interface, made by the code. Then, I developed to perform these changes in background.

I recorded this video to show what it happens, because when I took a print screen, it refreshes and works normally.

What can I do to resolve this problem?

[Video](https://copy.com/LM2IVGi4F7zW)

Thanks!

Comment: As a general observation, ui updates *must* be performed on the main thread.  The easiest way to do that is to use `dispatch_async`

Comment: David, really using in all calls of uialertview solved my problems. Thanks